# Type cast from Java.Lang.Object to native CLR type in MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android

How to cast Java.Lang.Object to some native type?

Example:

ListView adapter contains instances of native type Message. When i am trying to get SelectedItem from ListView it returns instance of Message type casted to Java.Lang.Object, but I can't find solution to cast Java.Lang.Object back to Message.

```
var message = (Message)list.SelectedItem;
// throws  Error    5   Cannot convert type 'Java.Lang.Object' to 'Message'
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After long time debuging, have found the solution:

```
public static class ObjectTypeHelper
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
    {
        var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
 var message = list.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).Cast<Message>();
 bundle.PutInt("Message", message.ID);
```

After careful sdk study have found MonoDroid integrated extension for this purpose:

```
public static TResult JavaCast<TResult>(this Android.Runtime.IJavaObject instance)
where TResult : class, Android.Runtime.IJavaObject
Member of Android.Runtime.Extensions
```

Comment: Comment by [user 915147](http://stackoverflow.com/users/915147/) (was edited into the answer): This extension is seriously limited, you can't apply to generic collection type like `List<T>` or `T[]` where T itself is type parameter.

Comment: The advantage of the proposed extension method is that it works with types that do not implement IJavaObject

Comment: that extension method works perfectly. just what i need

Comment: Great solution. Worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

The least magical way of getting a native type from the Spinner is to call

```
    message = ((ArrayAdapter<Message>)list.Adapter).GetItem(list.SelectedItemPosition);
```

Answer (score 5):

I used this code from above answer and it works fine to me

```
    public static class ObjectTypeHelper
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
    {
        var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
    }
}
```

and this is how I used

```
var selectedLocation = locationSpinner.SelectedItem.Cast<Location>();
```

I am able to get my location object fine from spinner

Answer (score 1):

For generic collections, the right answer would be to use JavaList, which is a Java.Lang.Object and also implements IList. But it involves more work that's for sure. This is actually just an adapter for Java's ArrayList implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try the JavaCast<> method (most of the views implement this)(not tested):

var message = list.SelectedItem.JavaCast< Message >();

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason GetChildAtPosition is not possible, serialise the object to json string and then deserialise the string back to native class.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers are correct but I found the simplest way for my case was to make the object a subclass of Java.Lang.Object.

For example I'm writing a Android app in Monotouch, mimicking the concept of a UITableView in iOS using the ExpandableListAdapter, which requires the equivalent of UITableViewCells, so I subclassed cell objects from Java.Lang.Object allowing me to implement a subclass of ExpandableListAdapter such as

```
public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int position, int childPosition)
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me:

```
public class HolderHelper<T> : Java.Lang.Object {
    public readonly T Value;

    public HolderHelper (T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

test:

```
chkFileName.Tag = new HolderHelper<LinkInfo> (item);
LinkInfo link= (chkFileName.Tag as HolderHelper<LinkInfo>).Value;
```